# Apple Java 1.6 Specific Classes in Cross-Platform Application

Tags: java, macos, cross-platform

I am developing a Java 1.6 based cross-platform (Mac OS X, Win and Linux) application. For better integration on Mac Os platform I have to use Mac OS X specific classes, which are neither available on other platform's JDK or JRE nor can be distributed with the application.

My questions is what is the ***best*** strategy to keep code compilable on both Mac OS X and Win platforms without maintaining two different versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a play with ClassLoaders. It is very similar for plugin development, at least there is used often:

you will build the main, cross platform application
you will declare an interface
you will create a "plugin loader" which will load available plugins. on macosx the mac one, on windows the windows one.

develop and build 3 plugins: mac, linux, windows

-autolink it at runtime with classloader.

Answer (score 1):

I think you won't be able to compile code that *uses* those classes, unless you restrict *all uses* to reflection. And that probably leads to a lot more problems than it's worth.

You could extract the Apple-Specific parts into a separate artifact/project and compile that only on Mac. And reference *that* via a pre-defined (shared) interface in the main project. This way you can simply try to load the Apple-specific code via reflection and if that doesn't work, use a dummy implementation.